# How to display a database table in .phtml file

Tags: magento2, database

I have created a custom module and created a database table using install schema like below:

```
id      color     price_component
1       white     0
2       red       4
3       green     8
4       black     12
```

How can I display this table in my .phtml file?

I'm new to Magento. If someone can explain this step by step that would be really helpful.

Comment: You Mean Admin custom grid @Hemal

Comment: yes something like that i need to display that table in my frontend .phtml file

Comment: Check Below i have updated you the answer @Hemal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used this for getting table in phtml file

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('your_table_name');

//Select Data from table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Comment: No if table are there than you can get directly.If you have model than called model instance of calling connection.

Comment: You can use whatever you want and $result is array that will get all value and print value by using foreach.

Comment: If you get your answer than please mark as solved

Comment: I think you are very new. used foreach ($reult as $results){
print_r($results);
 }
Used under php

Answer (score 0):

You need to create block, template and layout files for this. Create a new file app\code\Your_ExtensionName\Your_ModuleName\Block\Post.php

```
<?php
namespace Your_ExtensionName\Your_ModuleName\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Post extends Template
{
    protected $mymodulemodelFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Your_ExtensionName\Your_ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory $mymodulemodelFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->mymodulemodelFactory = $mymodulemodelFactory;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    public function getPosts(){
        $collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create();
        return $collection;     
    }
}
```

Now create layout file app\code\Your_ExtensionName\Your_ModuleName\view\frontend\layout\Your_ModuleName_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Your_ExtensionName\Your_ModuleName\Block\Post" name="posts" template="Your_ExtensionName_Your_ModuleName::post.phtml">                
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>               
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create app\code\Your_ExtensionName\Your_ModuleName\view\frontend\templates\post.phtml

```
<?php $collection = $this->getPosts(); ?>
<div class="yourtable">
    <?php foreach ($collection as $item){ ?>
                 <div class="yourtable">   
                    <?php 
                        // Display your data
                    ?>
                 </div>
     <?php  } ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Learning_Coder is the above answer working fine for you, for me block is not calling